# Api working fine in Postman but not in code Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I have this request in web api

```
            Connection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[SetIDByPhoneNumber]", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", student.PhoneNumber);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();
            int i=  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            if (i >= 1)
            {
                response.Massage = "Found One";
                response.Status = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                response.Massage = "Nothing -_-";
                response.Status = 0;
            }
```

And This Post method in Xamarin Form

```
string url = "MY URL (Which is a real website IP ADDRESS)";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Student.PhoneNumber");
        StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Response responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);
```

[Here you can see api is working well in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Ig6.png)

After running it on Android I got "object reference is not set to an instance of an object" and Response 0

I dont know what is the problem. My SQL stored procedure is working fine api is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jsonData` isn't JSON, try:

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { PhoneNumber = "45656" });
```

Comment: Oh man, you saved my life! I stacked in this problem for 2 days. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help @MahirMuzahid 

Answer (score 0):

I think your return Type is off. You do it like this the appropriate headers should be set, and it should be recognized as a valid json.

```
public JsonResult YourAction()
{
    // Your Code
    return Json(new {student.PhoneNumber});
}
```